# How can I limit, or ignore, large records from the results

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

Currently I am fetching logs from azure analytics and doing some post processing on a different app, the issue is that some records (aka rows) exceed the data size the app can process.

I have added the following at the end of the query:

```js
| take 50;
set truncationmaxsize=20480; //20MB
```

But the way it works is quite strange as it although seems to limit the number of records returned depending on the `truncationmaxsize` value, because certain records are too large they make the query fail if I decrease the size.

So I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, or rather to ignore rows that contain too much data.

Answer (score 2):

There's a standard column in Log Analytics called [_BilledSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-standard-columns#_billedsize) and it should display the total size of that entry.

Be sure to swap `Usage` for the name of your actual table.

An example query could be something like the following:

```
Usage
| where _BilledSize < 20480
```

If it's the app is failing at overall size, may it make sense to split the data up when ingesting?

```
Usage
| where TimeGenerated between (floor(ago(3h), 1h) .. floor(ago(2h), 1h))
```

As an alternative perhaps identifying the heavy time periods could be useful too:

```
Usage
| summarize sum(_BilledSize) by floor(TimeGenerated, 1h)
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed.